# Faraday Json validation before .post

Tags: json, api, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, faraday

Currently using Faraday to do some http request to certain api.
I want to validate the body + header at step of `.post`. 
However, when calling the `.post` the body is set and send.

So! I was wondering if it is possible to setup a schema validation at the step of `.post`(I did receive the Json schema validation from the API receiver side)

I am able to use the Faraday_Middleware using the `def call` to intercept, but was it possible to turn the request into Json form and validate them?

Gem Info: Gem `faraday` ~> 0.9, Gem `faraday_middleware`, gem `jbuilder`, gem `json-schema`

Answer (score 0):

When initially asking this question, I have no clear picture of how the Faraday works, in term of sending request and getting the response. But now it is more clear that, it might not be so easy to turn the request into JSON form and validate all of the information as whole.

The reason been is that, when Faraday send the information, the information package is bundle in the form of an object(or connection rather). You could validate the individual part of the information from connection. And currently there is no easy way to validate connection as a whole. (You could setup some header or body merging json method, then validate both at once. However, if that is the case, why not individually validate to be more accurate)

Bottom line is that, if we want to validate response or request as whole, we need to access the request and response individual fields (header, or body) and validate them separately in middleware.

In order to setup middleware

```
        Faraday.new(_proxy, _headers, _ssl) do |conn|
          conn.request :json # <---- what you send
          conn.response :xml,  :content_type => /\bxml$/ .  # <---- what you received
          conn.use _Validator_class, _parameter1, _parmeter2  
            #Validator_class should is where actual middleware been setup

          conn.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
               #^ should aways set this. Even it is default_adapter. 
               #  if you work in big project, other faraday gem might mess with this. 
               #  so it is best to manually set the default.
        end
```

```
class _Validator < Faraday::Middleware
   method initialize(app = nil, _parameter1, _parameter2)
        #blah #blah  <---- your code setup
        super(app)
   end 

   method call(env)
     #do your magic
     after_call(env) <<---- required
   end 

   method after_call
     # if you want to mess with out going information 
     # you can do so right over here 
     # but most of time just leave as 
     @app.call(env).on_complete do |_env|
    end
   end
end
```

```
env.header <----- your header, in the format you packaged
env.body   <----- your body, same as header above

setup in the call method section for close up validation.
```